# What is the limit of $x \tan (ax+\arctan(b/x)$) as $x \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $x \tan (ax+\arctan(b/x)$) as $x \to 0$. 
I can't use de l'Hopital's method and derivatives but only notable limits.
Please can someone help me with a clear solution?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. $x\tan (ax+\tan^{-1}(b/x))$ or $x\tan(ax) + \tan^{-1}(b/x)$? What are $a$ and $b$ (positive? negative?) I'd say $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x\tan(ax) + \tan^{-1}(b/x)$ for $b > 0$ is doable. What is "$\tan^{-1}(\infty)$" ?

Comment: Is it $x \tan(ax) + \arctan(b/x)$ or $x \tan\Big(ax + \arctan(b/x)\Big)$?

Comment: I'm sorry it is xtan(ax+arctan(b/x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\tan(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}$ we find
$$x\tan\left(ax+\arctan\frac bx\right)=x\cdot\frac{\tan ax+\frac bx}{1-\frac bx\tan ax}=\frac{x\tan ax+b}{1-ab\cdot\frac{\tan ax}{ax}}$$
Thus if $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan t}t= 1$ is a "notable limit" and $a\ne0$ (we divided by $a$ in the process!),  $ab\ne 1$, we obtain $$\frac b{1-ab}$$ as limit. 
Incidentally, with $a=0$ we also obtain that $x\tan\arctan \frac bx=b\to b$. If $ab=1$, the limit does not exist.